# Vectorized liner model

Tags: python, r, linear-regression, statsmodels

Using lm() in *R* I can do the following

```
fit <- lm(organ_volumes~sex+genotype, data=factors)
```

where organ volumes is a matrix where each column is a different variable. Each column in turn is fit to a linear model as described in the *lm* docs:

> If response is a matrix a linear model is fitted separately by least-squares to each column of the matrix.

Is there any way to do something similar in Python using *statsmodels* rather than having to loop over each column, which is much slower than the R method?

Comment: I don't think statsmodels allow for multi response linear model. You have to use scikit learn.

Comment: statsmodels does not have this yet, https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/5382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following in scikit, just note that sometimes for correlated dependent variables, the output is different from R:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data= iris['data'],
                     columns= iris['feature_names'] )

from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
X = df[['sepal length (cm)','sepal width (cm)']]
Y = df[['petal length (cm)','petal width (cm)']]
clf.fit(X,Y)
clf.coef_

array([[ 1.77559255, -1.33862329],
       [ 0.723292  , -0.47872132]])
```

In R:

```
data = as.matrix(iris[,-5])
lm(data[,c(1,3)] ~ data[,c(2,4)])

Call:
lm(formula = data[, c(1, 3)] ~ data[, c(2, 4)])

Coefficients:
                            Sepal.Length  Petal.Length
(Intercept)                  3.4573        2.2582     
data[, c(2, 4)]Sepal.Width   0.3991       -0.3550     
data[, c(2, 4)]Petal.Width   0.9721        2.1556
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm just trying something out like this, but I have quadratic terms in my formula so I'm trying to get it to work with patsy.

Comment: that's a bit more complicated, you might have to use sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures